# Expanding Slide Down Box Menu with jQuery and CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've implemented "Slide Down Box Menu" in my project website.But i have a problem to expand this menu to further submenus. I'm new to jQuery. I tried to expand it but every time it fails :(

Here is the demo of the menu from where i downloaded it.

[Slide Down Box demo](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlideDownBoxMenu/)

So I'm seeking you for help, Thanks in advance. :)

```
<div class="sdt_box">
<a href="#">Job Board Website</a>
      <ul><li> submenu item1 </li>
          <li> submenu item1 </li>
          <li> submenu item1 </li>
     </ul>
<a href="#">Shopping Cart</a>
<a href="#">Interactive Maps</a>
```

Comment: This has little chance to be answered like this. Please show the code where you tried to make a submenu. Also go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and try to make a testbed where it should work but fails to. After you did that I'm sure more people will be willing to help you.

Comment: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/16/slide-down-box-menu/

Comment: @SoonDead i'm not able to upload file so that u can see my modification. And on jsfiddle.net i'm not understanding it to fully implement my code.

Comment: Don't upload your file. It's text. Copy and paste the text from it in your edited question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CFcVB/2/ @SoonDead i uploaded it but demo is not working properly. So you can see the demo from privious link. So i want to expand it further to add more submenus. Projects menu have three submenu and i want to add submenus to the Projects submenu on hover effect.

Comment: I have cleaned up your code a little bit: http://jsfiddle.net/CFcVB/4/ .

Comment: @SoonDead thank you. But i need submenu item of "Job Board Website" on its hover event.
http://jsfiddle.net/CFcVB/5/